# Calculate the contour integral for the vector field $z^2 e_1 + x^2 e_2 + y^2 e_3$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

The contour that I am given is a circle radius a with centre $(1,1,0)$. So what I thought is to do the parameterisation $\vec x(t)$ = $(1 + a\cos(t), 1 + a\sin(t),  
 0)$ with $t$ going from $0$ to $2\pi$, but this seems to just get me $0$ which I don't think is the right answer.

Any Help?

Edit: so I have that parameterisation. I then did $d\vec x(t)$/dt = $(-asin(t), acos(t), 0)$

Now as we have the vector field given above. I times $(1 + acos(t))^2$ with $(acos(t))$ and integrate this between 0 and 2pi which gives me 0.

Comment: Well if the vector field is conservative then the answer would be zero, is this field conservative?

Comment: I don't know, the curl is not 0 so no?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be conservative.

Comment: I was just asking, it's a great way to know you've definitely made a mistake. Unfortunately I'm on mobile so someone will find your mistake

Comment: @PaulAljabar Do you know how to calculate this? Have I parameterised wrong?

Comment: You parametrize it correctly. you probably didn't notice $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2 t dt = \pi \ne 0$.

Comment: @achillehui But do I not need to time by the derivative of the parameter too

Comment: I got the intergral between 0 and 2pi of $(1 + acos(t))^2(acos(t))$

Comment: The term proportional to $\cos(t)$ and $\cos(t)^3$ doesn't contribute to the final result. This is because $\cos(t+\pi) = -\cos(t)$. You only need to keep the term $2a^2\cos(t)^2$ in your integral.

Comment: Seems to me that there’s some missing information. Why are you assuming in your parameterization that the circle lies in the $x$-$y$ plane?

Comment: @amd it says  "traversed in the positive sense" but I don't know what that means

Comment: That just means that you go counterclockwise around the circle.

Comment: @amd It's in the z=0 plane of radius if that's any help too

Comment: Yes. That was implicit in your parameterization, but missing from the initial description of the contour.

Comment: @amd http://puu.sh/vXjsP/eb9fa0504b.png I'm doing part b

Comment: @amd Hey not sure if you've seen my comment. Thanks

Comment: It would’ve been good to have included that information in your question. Anyway, instead of making us guess what you might’ve done wrong, please include the details of your attempt at a solution to the problem.

Comment: @amd Ok edited. I get the stuff from putting the parameterisation into the vector field given and then timesing by the derivative

Comment: @amd I don't get what information I missed out? Also that's all I can do on the question

Comment: And then what? As your instructors probably still tell you to do: show your work!

Comment: @amd So i do the integral between 0 and 2pi of $(1+acos(t))^2(cos(t))$ which gives me 0, hence my problem as 0 probably isn't the right answer. Now you have a go and see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this exercise by doing the following:

Let's use cylindrical coordinates so that $\gamma (t)=  (1+a\cos(t),1+a\sin(t),0)$, $t\in [0,2\pi)$ is your curve, and $\gamma ' (t) = (-a\sin(t), a\cos(t), 0)$.

This way you get that $$ \int_{\gamma} \vec{A} \cdot \vec{dl} = \int_0^{2\pi} A(\gamma)\cdot \gamma ' dt =\\ \int_0^{2\pi}\left(0,(1+a\cos(t))^2,(1+a\sin(t))^2\right) \cdot \left((-a\sin(t), a\cos(t), 0)\right) dt=\\ \int_0^{2\pi}(a\cos(t))\cdot(1+a\cos(t))^2  =  2 \pi a^2 $$
(You may find all the steps to solve this last integral on [this link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cleft(a%5Ccos%5Cleft(t%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Ccdot%5Cleft(1%2Ba%5Ccos%5Cleft(t%5Cright)%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%20%20))

Note that you can also use Stokes Theorem (a.k.a curl theorem) given that the circle is a closed curve. Therefore, you have:
$$ \int_{\gamma = \delta S} \vec{A} \cdot \vec{dl} = \int_ S (\vec{\nabla} \times\vec{A})\cdot \vec{n} dS$$
Where $S$ is the surface covered by the curve and $\vec{n} = (0,0,1)$ since it's traversed in the positive way - we use the right hand rule -.

Given that $$\vec{\nabla} \times\vec{A} = (2y,2z,2x) \\(2y,2z,2x)\cdot(0,0,1) = 2x $$

We get $$\int_S 2x dS$$ So, since our curve is $$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = a^2$$ the integral becomes$$\int_{1-a}^{1+a}2x\left(\int_{-\sqrt{a^2 - (x-1)^2} +1}^{\sqrt{a^2 - (x-1)^2} +1}dy\right)dx = \int_{1-a}^{1+a} 4x\sqrt{a^2 - (-1 + x)^2}dx$$ Solving this integral you should get the same result as before, but as you can see, it is way harder.

I hope I didn't get any of the calculus wrong.

Comment: You're right! Just edited it. Thanks